# Cannot use GoogleServicesJson build action in .NET 7.0

Tags: firebase, push-notification, google-play-services, maui, .net-7.0

I am in the process of setting up push notifications in my .NET MAUI application, using Firebase.
When trying to include the google-services.json file in the project, however, I cannot set the build action correctly.

After doing research, the build action is tied to `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement` package (which is usually accessed through `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base`) however the build action never shows up - I can only assume that this is due to the `.Base` package being made for .NET 6.0.

My code makes use of packages which are built for .NET 7.0 (Maui.CommunityToolkit & Maui.Controls.Maps), so rolling back to .NET 6.0 is not an ideal solution.

I have tried to install `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base`(net6.0), build action doesn't show up.
I have cleaned solution, rebuilt, restarted Visual Studio, reloaded project - nothing helps.
I have tried manually setting build action in .csproj file after install - doesn't work.
I have tried to install other libraries which include Base or Basement - no change.
I have ensured that the .csproj conditions are referring to .net 7.0 and not 6.0.
I have looked for any pre-release or branch versions of GooglePlayServices.Base - there is only a branch for .net 8.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you mean that build action isn't showing up in the Visual Studio UI. That doesn't mean it's not available.

Install the package needed and add this to your csproj file:

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'"">
    <GoogleServicesJson Include="google-services.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Also see a complete guide here: https://cedricgabrang.medium.com/firebase-push-notifications-in-net-maui-android-32c808844d7e

Comment: Hi Gerald, thanks for the quick reply. I had tried manually setting the build action in the csproj previously, with still no luck. I still get the following error when trying to build:
`[FirebaseApp] Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project.`
`[FirebaseInitProvider] FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful`

Comment: Hm interesting, I'd have to have a look at it further, but as far as I know you should be able to make this work. Where did you put that file in your project? Is there anything in the build output that says it can't find the file? Do you see the file in the outputted binary?

Comment: It seems like my installation of Plugin.Firebase was causing issues, most likely due to the file path being too long when downloading initially (had to change a registry flag to download dependencies). After cleaning my installation and redownloading the relevant packages, I seem to have gotten notifications to work. Thanks for the assistance, going to mark your initial answer as the fix as it's the standard fix for this situation

Comment: Glad you figured it out! I think you can get around the long path issue on Windows by adding the NuGet package with `dotnet add` too :)