# Firebase/google-services.json Related Build Issues in MAUI.NET 7

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, maui

Greets,

Using Visual Studio 2022, MAUI.NET 7 for Android

I'm trying to add Firebase push support to an Android MAUI.NET 7 app.  I've been through the guides.  I have the backend part all squared away and needed to add the resultant google-services.json file to my project (which I did) and set it's "Build Action" property to googleservces.  Additionally adding the Xamarin.Google.Dagger package (to the other packages required for Firebase) didn't reveal the property setting I needed.  I found some posts that indicated to add the following to my .csproj file:

```
<Import Project="C:\Users\e_hac\.nuget\packages\xamarin.googleplayservices.basement\118.2.0.4\build\monoandroid12.0\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets" Condition="Exists('C:\Users\e_hac\.nuget\packages\xamarin.googleplayservices.basement\118.2.0.4\build\monoandroid12.0\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets')" />
```

After doing so I did get the expected "Build Action" property setting however now I get the  error below, which both doesn't make a lot of sense and also I can't seem to find anyone else reporting the same issue.

> Failed to Read or Deserialize GoogleServicesJson file:
> Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml
> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: There was an
> error deserializing the object of type
> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks.GoogleServices. Encountered
> unexpected character '<'. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Encountered
> unexpected character '<'.    at
> System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader
> reader, XmlException exception)    at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlJsonReader.Read()    at
> System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement()    at
> System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.IsStartElement(XmlDictionaryString localName,
> XmlDictionaryString namespaceUri)    at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.InternalIsStartObject(XmlReaderDelegator
> reader)    at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator
> xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName)    at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator
> reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver
> dataContractResolver)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator
> reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver
> dataContractResolver)    at
> System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader
> reader)    at
> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks.GoogleServicesJsonProcessor.ProcessJson(String
> packageName, Stream json)    at
> Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Tasks.ProcessGoogleServicesJson.Execute()  TMCP    C:\Users\e_hac.nuget\packages\xamarin.googleplayservices.basement\118.2.0.4\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement.targets 71

The AndroidManifest.xml file is fine.  The google-services.json file appears to be fine.  Has anyone else seen this?  If so, any resolution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Just found this post [Cannot use GoogleServicesJson build action in .NET 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76253895/cannot-use-googleservicesjson-build-action-in-net-7-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, this was caused by is what we used to call an ID10T (or PEBKAC) error.

Basically (somehow) I set the "Build Action" property for the AndroidManifest.xml file from "None" to GoogleServicesJson.  Once I stepped away from the keyboard to grab a beverage it came to me.

Anyway, hopefully this will help someone in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

I created a project hosted on github repository which use maui blazor hybrid to send push notification in generic strategy and builder way, that can help you to send push notification in MAUI. the repository is private I will share with you that by tomorrow.

Comment: Excellent!  I'd love to have a look at that as I doubt this is the last issue I'll have.  Thanks!